# How to use ASP.Net MVC Child Actions with VS 2017 C# and MVC 5

Tags: model-view-controller, controller, view, action, partial

I have a scenario but do not know if it is possible to do this with child actions.

I do not have any code to show. Basically, there would be a simple list on the left side of a view containing summary data. On each line of the list there would also be a 'view details' link or button. So, I want the user to click that link/button, and then on the right side I want more details about the particular selected item to be displayed. The user could then click on the view details for another item and view those details etc.

How is this best achieved in ASP.Net MVC?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So if they click more than 1 "view details" it should show all details in the right panel? Or the newly clicked detail should replace the one that was there?

Comment: The newly clicked detail should replace the one that was there

Comment: You can use `Ajax` to retrieve the data about an item when a link is clicked, then use the returned data to populate the div or whatever element you are using to display the item info in the right panel.

Comment: Would you be able to give me a code example? Each row on the left would have a button..how would you know which one was clicked etc? Any help really appreciated.

Comment: Added an example answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example for the OP, this may or may not be the best way, but it will work:

So your left panel has buttons or links, if the text of your button/link is enough to pull back the relevant data from the server, just pass that to the server via `Ajax`, else if you wanted to use ids or some unique identifier, you could append that to the id property of your buttons/links and then pass that to the server, I will let you decide which you want to use:

```
//Example HTML
<div id="panelLeft">
   <button id="btnOne" class="btnInfo">Info on Cats</button>
   <br/>
   <button id="btnTwo" class="btnInfo">Info on Dogs</button>
</div>

//Assuming you are using JQuery
//Either in your page add a script tag with this code, or add a script file
//to your project and import it into your page (View)
$(function(){
      //Add click events to all your buttons by using the common className btnInfo
      $('.btnInfo').on('click', function(){
            const serverSideData = $(this).text(); //If you are using the text
            //of the button to find the info server side
            $.ajax({
                  url: "yourUrlToServerSideMethod",
                  type: "POST",
                  data: { yourServerSideParameter: serverSideData },
                  success: function(data){
                      //Successfully posted to server and got response
                      //If data is in JSON format, you can parse it with JSON.parse()

                      //Clear your div on the right which displays the item data
                      $('#divRightPanelInfo).html('');
                      $('#divRightPanelInfo).append(data); //If this is just a string
                      //Or create some pretty element(s) and append that to div

                  },
                  error: function(jqXHR, exception){
                      //Handle error, show error label or something
                  }
              });
       });
 });
```

Comment: Thank you! The text of the button will always say "View", so the text will be the same. I need to get an (int) id to an action on the mvc controller.. This id is the only data item that uniquely identifies each row. The current action I have returns a partial view - will I need to return something different for this? ..and therefore would I need another action? Also, the rows and therefore the  buttons are created in generated in a foreach.. what's the best way to handle this for the id in the button markup?

Comment: @D.Man as you are iterating your `foreach` if you are using some custom class which has the id property you could just do `button id="btnViewData_(concatenate the id value of the object here)"` Then in the code above instead of using `$(this).text()` you could do `const serverSideData = $(this).prop('id').replace('btnViewData_', '');` As for what you need server side, you will need to create a method which accepts an integer (your id) and returns the data you want to show in the right panel as either string or some other format, just make sure the method has a matching return type.

Comment: Thanks. Can I access the "value" of the button from the script code, as I can set this in the foreach? What do I need to return the data as from the MVC Action? A PartialViewResult or something else?

Comment: I should maybe add, the partial view displaying the details/child data has a viewmodel too

Comment: If you are returning a partial view for rendering inside the panel on the right, returning it as PartialView should be fine, then you can do `$('#divRightPanelInfo).append(data);`

Comment: Got it working! Success! Thanks, Ryan, really appreciated.

Comment: @D.Man no problem, glad I could help, if my answer was of use, please mark it as the accepted answer. :)